# Having problems trying to set an adapter inside an AsyncTask

Tags: android, arraylist, android-asynctask, android-arrayadapter

I  need to retrieve some huge data from one database when an activity is started. To prevent a user with a frozen window, I decided to run a ProgressDialog while data is being processed.

From OnCreate I call my initDb Class:

new initDb().execute();

And then to do this I have one class inside my activity's class:

```
public class initDb extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    ProgressDialog mDialog = new ProgressDialog(ClientsReg.this);

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        mDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
        mDialog.show();
    }


    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {

        opendb();
        listCities();
    return null;


    }

@Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void unused) {
        // Pass the result data back to the main activity
        mDialog.dismiss();
    }
```

}

The real problem happens while setting the adapter:

```
private void listCities() {


      mRedrawHandler.sleep(100000);


        c = db.executeSQL("SELECT * FROM RegDB WHERE Reg_Type = 1 AND cad_uzkow = 0 ORDER BY _id DESC");

        //add some list items
        ArrayList<String> finalList = new ArrayList<String>();

        c.moveToFirst();


        while (!c.isAfterLast()){

            finalList.add(c.getString(0) + ")"+ c.getString(5));            
            c.moveToNext();
        }


        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                R.layout.row, R.id.itemShow, finalList);
        sp.setAdapter(adapter);


    }
```

It always happen to crash on sp.setAdapter(adapter);

Any ideas?

Thank you!

Comment: Can you post crash log from logcat?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try taking the finalList as an attribute of your initDb class this way you can populate it on the doInBackground method and then us it on the onPostExecute, like this:

```
    public class initDb extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    ProgressDialog mDialog = new ProgressDialog(ClientsReg.this);
    ArrayList<String> finalList;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        mDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
        mDialog.show();
    }


    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {

        opendb();
        listCities();
    return null;


    }

@Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void unused) {
        // Pass the result data back to the main activity

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                R.layout.row, R.id.itemShow, finalList);
        sp.setAdapter(adapter);

        mDialog.dismiss();
    }

private void listCities() {


      mRedrawHandler.sleep(100000);


        c = db.executeSQL("SELECT * FROM RegDB WHERE Reg_Type = 1 AND cad_uzkow = 0 ORDER BY _id DESC");

        //add some list items
        finalList = new ArrayList<String>();

        c.moveToFirst();


        while (!c.isAfterLast()){

            finalList.add(c.getString(0) + ")"+ c.getString(5));            
            c.moveToNext();
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should call:

```
sp.setAdapter(adapter);
```

in main UI thread. For example in `onPostExecute()` function. Always keep in mind that views (such as `ListView`) should only be accessed from main thread.

Answer (score 0):

You can't access the UI from other thread than the thread that created the UI. So in AsyncTask, you can't use doInBackground() for this purpose.